# AWS Inspector not updating Finding status to CLOSED

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum

We are running into an issue where we have applied all the fixes for Findings reported by the AWS Inspector. But, the Inspector Dashboard still reports them as Active instead of Closed. Interestingly, all the Findings related to Kernel updates are closed. Only Findings related to user packages installed via `yum` are not marked as Closed.

For example, one of the Findings is "CVE-2023-44487 - libnghttp2" which asks to update the `libnghttp2` to at least `0:1.41.0-1.amzn2.0.4`. We did the fix on the EC2 instance two days ago, but this is still marked as Active in the Inspector Dashboard.

Here's the screenshot of the Finding in the Inspector
[image]

And here's the output of `yum list libnghttp2`

```
$ sudo yum list libnghttp2
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Installed Packages
libnghttp2.x86_64       1.41.0-1.amzn2.0.4       @amzn2-core
Available Packages
libnghttp2.i686         1.41.0-1.amzn2.0.4       amzn2-core
```

Update:
Tried installing the i686 package to see if Inspector likes that. Didn't work. Here's the output of `yum list libnghttp2` after installing `i686`

```
sudo yum list libnghttp2
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Installed Packages
libnghttp2.i686        1.41.0-1.amzn2.0.4        @amzn2-core
libnghttp2.x86_64      1.41.0-1.amzn2.0.4        @amzn2-core
```

Comment: What's the `Last scanned at` field showing? Is the machine being actively scanned?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Currently, it is `October 25, 2023 5:07 PM (UTC-07:00)`. And it's updating fairly regularly. I had the same feeling it was not being scanned. But it is, that is how I got past the findings that required Kernel updates.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Removed the image and updated the question with full output of `sudo yum list libnghttp2`. Also, not sure how to "hard delete and then delete the right one" but I'll take a look around.

Comment: Also, I'm unsure why it's looking for a non-x86 version. Also, it doesn't look like Amazon repo provides `nonarch` versions for this lib https://ibb.co/VgCR0r2

Comment: Hm interesting - I can't think of anything else if the machine is being actively scanned. It should auto close. Are you sure you've remediated it on the target machine specified by the finding and perhaps not on another instance? At your own risk, maybe `sudo yum -y remove libnghttp2 && sudo yum install libnghttp2` might kick it into action but I'm out of ideas!

Comment: Yes, it is the same instance. I have tried reinstalling it multiple times, but the Inspector doesn't detect it. Anyway, thanks for the help. If I find a fix, I'll post it here.

Comment: Does reinstalling install both `i686` and `x86_64` together?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Update the question with output of `yum list` after installing the `i686`

Comment: Try each one on its own, let Inspector scan and then see what happens?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear in the previous message. But I only tried this on `libnghttp2`.

Comment: As in try it on each arch version separately, with the other one uninstalled .

Comment: I was able to give that a try—same error. Uninstalled the entire package and then only installed`x86_64` and then uninstalled it and installed `i686` :(. I'm going to give up on the AWS inspector for now. The Patch Manager is reporting all good so that's enough.